# Filter on relationship after fetching data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode7

I need to display a recipe list from Recipe entity that is filtered on category attribute which sets a relationship to RecipeCategory entity.

The following diagram should give you the structure.

[image]

I have

```
var recipes = [Recipe]()
var filteredRecipe = [Recipe]()
```

And filteredRecipe will have recipe objects that are filtered by the value of `name` attribute of RecipeCategory entity.

Below is a working code that works with filtering on title attribute.
This approach works because title is an attribute of Recipe entity.

```
filteredRecipes = recipes.filter({$0.title!.rangeOfString(lowercased) != nil})
```

But if I try to filter on category relationship (NSManagedObject) using `valueForKey()` like so

```
filteredRecipe = recipes.filter({$0.category!.valueForKey("name")!.rangeOfString(lowercased) != nil})
```

It won't filter and will return the full recipe list instead.

I've seen people using Predicate but I want to avoid making new fetch request every time. Instead I want to filter on the fetched data. How can I filter values on relationship attribute and get the filtered result of the main object (Recipe entity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a predicate without fetching from the store.  `NSPredicate` can be used against a collection as well as an `NSFetchRequest`.

You could also write the filter out:

```
let filteredRecipe = recipes.filter({
    if let category = $0.category {
        if let name = category.valueForKey("name") {
            return name.rangeOfString(lowercased) == nil
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
})
```

Personally, I would use a predicate instead:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category.name in %@", ["Main", "Desert", "Side"])
let filtered = recipes.filter({predicate.evaluateWithObject($0)})
```

### Update

Went and played with the filter a little more in a test project.  Here is the code with no `NSManagedObject` subclasses so `valueForKey` and optional casting is used judicially:

```
let filteredRecipe = recipes?.filter({
    if let category = $0.valueForKey("category") as? NSManagedObject {
        if let name = category.valueForKey("name") as? String {
            return name.rangeOfString(lowercased) == nil
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not see how I can compare string of `valueForKey("name")`  with a custom string - lowercased - in the question?

Comment: `lowercased` will have values like `main` `side` `dessert` and it will always have value. I need to know which recipe contains this value.

Comment: Thanks again! But I'm getting `Value of type 'NSRange' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed` on `return name.rangeOfString(lowercased) == nil
`

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be `!= nil` ? Otherwise I'm getting nothing assigned to filteredRecipe.

Comment: Yes, the logic in that filter is reversed.  Given that it is hard to read it again supports why using a predicate is better :)